# Wicket - how to use SelectOption with DropDownChoice?

Tags: java, wicket, dropdownchoice

I have a single setting that I want to use in multiple locations. I need to get and set an Integer value: 0, 1, 2, -1. The displayed string are not stored.

Fragment of the html:

```
<select wicket:id="thingPref">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Fragment of the Java.

```
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.select.SelectOption;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.DropDownChoice;

private SelectOption thingPreference; 

private void buildCommon()
{
    thingPreference = new SelectOption(Integer.toString(setting()), new Model<String>("dummy"));
    List<SelectOption> prefChoices = new ArrayList<SelectOption>();
    prefChoices.add(new SelectOption<String>("0", new Model<String>("Current Thing")));
    prefChoices.add(new SelectOption<String>("1", new Model<String>("One Prior Thing")));
    prefChoices.add(new SelectOption<String>("2", new Model<String>("Two Prior Things")));
    prefChoices.add(new SelectOption<String>("-1", new Model<String>("All Things")));
    DropDownChoice<SelectOption> prefselect = new DropDownChoice<SelectOption>("thingPref", 
            new PropertyModel<SelectOption>(this, "thingPreference"), prefChoices)
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected boolean wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications()
        {
            return true;
        }

        protected void onSelectionChanged(final String newSelection)
        {
            System.out.format("onSelectionChanged(%s)%n", newSelection);
        }
    };
    prefselect.setNullValid(false);
    prefselect.setRequired(true);
    add(prefselect);
}
```

Developer Tools shows html like this

```
<option value="3">[SelectOption [Component id = -1]]</option>
```

when I need

```
<option value="-1">All Things</option>
```

The solution does not look to be as simple as adding a renderer and I am not sure that the setting should use an enum. I am using Wicket 7.6. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.select.SelectOption` should be used with `org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.select.Select`, not with `org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.DropDownChoice`.

For your use case you can use either `DropDownChoice` or `Select`. In both cases you will need custom `IChoiceRenderer`.

`Select` should be preferred than `DropDownChoice` when you need more control on each and every option. `DropDownChoice` works with a list of POJOs.

Answer (score 0):

I applied a custom renderer to show the data options.

```
private static final List<Integer> TermSettings = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, -1);

ChoiceRenderer<Integer> choiceRenderer = new ChoiceRenderer<Integer>()
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Object getDisplayValue(Integer value)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case 0:
                return "Current Term";
            case 1:
                return "One Prior Term";
            case 2:
                return "Two Prior Terms";
            case -1:
                return "All Terms";
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException(value + " is not mapped!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getIdValue(Integer object, int index)
    {
        Integer idvalue = TermSettings.get(index);
        String strvalue = String.valueOf(idvalue);
        return strvalue;
    }
};
```